# Why fetch JavaScript in Laravel always return empty value?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm fetching the API from the system itself inside the blade template view. But I always return `{}`.

```
fetch("http://mylaravelapp.com/api/list")
.then(response => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

I already set CORS header inside my API using this library, https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors.

Comment: did you check on browser network section, did you get the result from server-side?

Comment: @Gulshan I already tested with POSTMAN, no issue.

Comment: The fetch promise is axios? I'm asking because you need to set csrf-token so have to be certain that has been set.

Comment: @SundayJohnson - *"The fetch promise is axios?"* Not if it's the built-in `fetch`, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. You're not checking that the HTTP request succeeded. **Lots** of people make this mistake, it's a flaw in the `fetch` API design, more [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog. You need to check `response.ok`.
2. [`response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) is an object with no own, enumerable properties, so `JSON.stringify` will return `"{}"` for it. To get the response, you must **read** the response body via one of the response object's methods, such as [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer), [`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData), or [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob).

So for instance:

```
fetch("http://mylaravelapp.com/api/list")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text(); // or .json(), .arrayBuffer(), ...
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to return JSON Data and use JSON dataType in your Fetch request